# Слово "паломник"

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "паломник"? Пытаюсь понять, от какого слова оно могло произойти, и ничего не идет на ум. Разве что "палка" в значении "посох"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну зачем же гадать, нарушая все мыслимые и немыслимые фонетические законы?
Загляните в словарь.
Слово "паломник" — иноязычное, к палке (точнее — к палу, пальцу, от которого палка произведено) отношения не имеет никакого.

Паломник образовано от латинского *palma* (пальма) с присоединением русского суффикса *-ник*.
В латинском есть аналогичные образования — *palmāriī, palmātī.*
Пальмовые ветви играли важную роль при исполнении обрядов, особенно в раннем христианстве. Так, к гробу Господню полагалось идти с пальмовыми ветвями, этот обряд и послужил началом паломничеству. Впоследствии, с распространением христианства на север, пальма заменялась другими растениями (на Руси — вербой) и понимание исходного смысла пропало.
Поэтому при проникновении самого понятия в русскую культуру слово было воспринято как самодостаточное и "переведено" по типу кальки: суффикс переведен, а корневая основа оставлена без перевода.